# evaluate a LambdaExpression?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-expressions

I'm making a LINQ lambda expression:

```
 Expression<Func<double, double, double>> add = (x, y) => x + y;
```

But now how would I evaluate it, say to find 2+3?

Comment: Do you really want to represent it as a Linq Expression?  You can evaluate a `Func<double, double, double>` just fine on its own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
var sum = add.Compile()(2,3);
```

There is some case your `Expression` does not have generic types, you have to use `DynamicInvoke` to execute it because the `Compile()` then will return a `Delegate`:

```
someNonGenericExpression.Compile().DynamicInvoke(2,3);
```

Answer (score 3):

In general, if you just want to *evaluate* the lambda, don't use `Expression<T>`, but rather just use your lambda to define a `Func<T>` directly:

```
Func<double, double, double> add = (x, y) => x + y;
double result = add(42.2, 52.1);
```

If you have an `Expression<T>` already for other reasons, and need to evaluate it, you can use [`Expression<T>.Compile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345362%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to convert it into a delegate:

```
Expression<Func<double, double, double>> add = (x, y) => x + y;
var asDelegate = add.Compile();
double result = asDelegate(42.2, 52.1);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Expression.Compile()` will compile your expression into a function/action. So do that and then invoke the method.

```
Expression<Func<double, double, double>> add = (x, y) => x + y;
Func<double, double, double> addFunc = add.Compile();
double result = addFunc(2, 3);
```